# Amazon Lex - Access MongoDB with Node.JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, amazon-web-services, amazon-lex

I have created a bot with Amazon Lex V2 and I have implemented a [code](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/LexRuntimeV2.html) on Node.JS to interact with Amazon Lex. Everything is working fine. I have a requirement of accessing the database when users ask certain questions to the bot. I use MongoDB for the database. I see there is a way using lambda. But then there is no proper documentation for V2. Is there any way I can access MongoDB with Node.js when users ask a certain question to Amazon Lex bot?

**Code**

```
var params = {
        botAliasId: 'XXXXXX', /* required */
        botId: 'XXXXXXXXX', /* required */
        localeId: 'en_US', /* required */
        requestContentType: 'text/plain; charset=utf-8', /* required */
        sessionId: req.body.sessionId.toString(), /* required */
        inputStream: req.body.message,
        responseContentType: "audio/mpeg",
        };
            lexruntimev2.recognizeUtterance(params, (err, data) => {
            if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
            else {console.log(data)}
```

Answer (score 0):

You most certainly can achieve your desired integration through the use of Lambda functions supporting your AWS Lex V2 bot.

The Lex V2 developer guide explains how you can link a Lambda function to your Lex bot and use the Lambda function to perform additional functions; like calling your MongoDB database.

In summary, you will need to assign your new Lambda function to your Lex bot. The Lambda function will be responsible for using the necessary user input fields to query the DB and then building up and returning an appropriate response message for Lex to consume.

The foramts are detailed in the linked developer guide.

[AWS Lex V2 Developer Guide - Lambda Functions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lexv2/latest/dg/lambda.html)